# Weighted sum of diagonal values is dominated by the sum of the singular values

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, matrix-calculus, svd

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ real matrix with $\det A \ge 0$, and let $\sigma_1 \le \sigma_2$ be its singular values. Let $0 \le x_1 \le x_2$. How to prove that $x_1 A_{11} +x_2A_{22} \le x_1 \sigma_1+x_2 \sigma_2$?

---

I have a proof, but it uses Riemannian geometry. I am looking for a more elementary proof.

**Equivalent formulation:**

Set $K=\{ A \in M_2 \, | \, \det A \ge 0 \, \, \text{ and the singular values of } A \, \text{are } \sigma_1,\sigma_2 \}$. Then
$$\max_{A \in K} x_1 A_{11} +x_2A_{22}=x_1 \sigma_1+x_2 \sigma_2.$$

It suffices to prove that the maximum is obtained at a diagonal matrix; for a diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries $A=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_{\alpha(i)})$, the claim reduces to the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)
$\sum_i x_i\sigma_{\alpha(i)} \le \sum_i x_i\sigma_i$, where $\alpha \in S_2$ is a permutation.(for dimension $2$ this can be verified directly by hand.)

---

I guess this should be well-known. Is there any reference in the literature?
Is it true for $n \times n$ matrices?

---

If $x_1=x_2$, then this reduces to $\text{tr}(A) \le \sigma_1+\sigma_2$ which is a classic easy result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is true irrespective of the determinant of $A$ or dimension $n$.  (I normally write singular values in the opposite order with $\sigma_1$ being largest but I'll try your notation)

$X:=diag(\mathbf x)$ i.e. a diagonal matrix with $x_{i,i} := x_i$ so $X\succeq \mathbf 0$.  And let $\Sigma_A$ have the singular values of $A$ in your ordering.

$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k,k}\cdot x_k = \text{trace}\Big(AX\Big)\leq \text{trace}\Big(\Sigma_A X\Big)= \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_{k}\cdot x_k$
by the **von Neumann Trace Inequality**